# Why is my View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) method not working on time?

Tags: android, view, visibility

I'm working on my Android demo which will launch a floating window when certain button is clicked. Then, by clicking the floating window the window itself will hide until the screenshot of current displayed window is taken, and then show itself.

Basically, **click floating window -- hide itself -- take screenshot -- display itself**.

I Googled around and managed to write some code to make it work. There is something weird: whenever I clicked the floating window, the window itself is not disappearing on time, namely my every screenshots contain the window's view.

The sequence seems to turned into **click floating window -- take screenshot -- hide itself -- display itself**. It shouldn't behave like this!

**The Code:**

```
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    floatIcon = new ImageView(this);
    floatIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;

    windowManager.addView(floatIcon, params);

    try {
        floatIcon.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // Get current time in nano seconds.
                        long pressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                        // If double click...(click interval should be longer than 2000)
                        if (pressTime - lastPressTime <= 2000) {
//                              createNotification();
//                              ServiceFloating.this.stopSelf();
                            mHasDoubleClicked = true;
                        } else {
                            mHasDoubleClicked = false;
                        }
                        lastPressTime = pressTime;
                        initialX = paramsF.x;
                        initialY = paramsF.y;
                        initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                        initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!mHasDoubleClicked && !mHasMoved) {
                            if (rootUtil == null) {
                                rootUtil = RootUtil.getInstance();
                            }

                            while (floatIcon.isShown()) {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(300);
                                    floatIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            Vibrator vb = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            vb.vibrate(100);

                            String tempFileName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
                            rootUtil.execute("screencap -p /sdcard/" + tempFileName + ".png");
                        }
                        floatIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                        paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatIcon, paramsF);
                        if ((int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX) < 3 && (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY) < 3) {
                            mHasMoved = false; //Move distance within 3 is not recognized as a real move
                        } else {
                            mHasMoved = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

I'm stuck here for several days. Really appreciate it if anyone could help or give me a hint.

Ps.
I can't understand why no one seems to be interested in this question, is it because that this question is not worth answering at all or just that I'm asking questions in the wrong way/style here?

Comment: Anyone knows the reason? I've made several other experiments, none of them could work.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**

Although nobody answered my question after about a week. I managed to solve this problem, and now I want to post the solve here in case anyone encountered the same kind of question in the future.

I did solve the problem of **click floating window -- hide itself -- take screenshots -- display itself**  sequence with the implementation of **AsyncTask** provided by Android.

In the `onPreExecute()` method of AsyncTask, I put the code of hiding floating window in it.

In the `doInBackground()` method of AsyncTask, I put the code of taking screenshots in it.

In the `onPostExectue()` method of AsyncTask, I put the code of displaying floating window in it.

Then at the `onTouch()` method of my `onCreate()`, just initialise the AsyncTask and execute it.

Everything works exactly as I expected, I have no idea why the previous code is not working. I've tried to start a new Thread and use Thread.join to wait for the thread of taking screenshots' finish, and then display the floating window, even this is not working), but AsyncTask works.

Just hope this will help someone, and I do wish someone could explain to me as well.

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help to someone, I also faced this issue. But in my case, I used RotateAnimation to the View. If I comment the RotateAnimation code, then View.INVISIBLE is working.